# Getting data not defined error while accessing data from Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have Collection named products with 4 documents.

I am trying to access the data and write it to the document or log it to console.

However I keep getting the following error

```
app-min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Here is my code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", even => {
    const app = firebase.app();

    const db = firebase.firestore();


        const productsRef = db.collection('products');

        const query = productsRef.orderBy('price', 'desc')

        query.get()
                .then(products => {
                    products.forEach(doc => {
                        data = doc.data();
                        document.write(`${data.name} at $${data.price} <br>`);
                        console.log(data);
                    })
                })
});
```

Not too sure where to go from here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems straight-forwardly about the undeclared "data" identifier in the then function, as @Vlad suggests below.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting let before data like this:

let data = doc.data()